# Don't open an untitled file if OS X Lion will reopen a document

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion

I've got a Core Data Document Based App (OS X) that opens an untitled document if the user hasn't specified a document to open on startup.  Now that Lion reopens documents on launch, I need to know how to prevent this untitled document from opening if there are documents to be reopened from the last time the program ran.

Previously, I did some checking in

`- (BOOL) applicationShouldOpenUntitledFile: (NSApplication *) sender`

and returned `YES` or `NO` appropriately.  What should I check now to prevent an untitled document from being opened when there are documents to restore?

Answer (score 2):

From Lion's release notes:

> As part of the restorable windows feature, the application delegate
>   may not be asked to create an Untitled window at launch in some
>   circumstances. This was found to cause crashes in certain apps, so
>   these apps will maintain 10.6 behavior of more often opening Untitled
>   windows. When these apps are recompiled on 10.7, they will acquire the
>   10.7 behavior. For maximum compatibility, do not depend on being asked
>   to create an Untitled window at launch.

Basically, they're saying "it may not work and we're not going to say why, so it's best not to rely on it at all."

Comment: Yeah, this has to be one of the weirdest bits of documentation in Lion. There must be some way around this, because it's *really* annoying.

Comment: What you see (in the docs and the behavior that seems to back it up) is what you get. File bug reports - it's the only way they'll know how much developers need this to function properly... but they may not care, given their new model.

Comment: The wording of the question sounds like the problem is the other way around, though: It *is* creating an untitled document, in circumstances in which the questioner does not want it to.

Comment: The last sentence suggests to me you may not be asked either way so you have no say in the matter at all. Further, it sounds like Lion (10.7 and 10.7.1 as far as I can tell) makes some "educated guesses" using logic they've not gotten around to defining yet (if ever).